# When I add a stream subscription on a DOM element, and then remove the element later, will dart:html take care of the subscription, too?

Tags: dart

Often, I create an element from which I need to listen to (Mouse)Events. Then, later, I don't need the button anymore, so I remove it. Like this:

```dart
var button = new ButtonElement()
  ..onClick.listen((_) => print("Clicked!"));

// ... somewhere else in the code or in the callback above
button.remove();
```

Should I also take care of the `onClick` subscription (to prevent memory leaks) or is that handled for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this will not be done automatically by removing the element from the DOM, as you might re-insert it at another point. The source code for `remove()` is fairly simple:

```dart
Node remove() {
  // TODO(jmesserly): is parent == null an error?
  if (parentNode != null) {
    parentNode.nodes.remove(this);
  }
  return this;
}
```

However, if there are no other references to the object and the Element class gets cleaned up by the garbage collector, then I expect the subscriptions will go with it (though I don't know enough to know how to confirm this from the source!).

Comment: If the element isn't referenced by a variable that can not be garbage collected itself the subscriptions are freed and collected.